# Time Series Analysis - unevenly spaced measures - pandas + statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels

I have two numpy arrays light_points and time_points and would like to use some time series analysis methods on those data.

I then tried this :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'time':time_points[:]})
rdf =  pd.DataFrame({'light':light_points[:]})
rdf.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='w',start=0,periods=len(rdf.light))
#rdf.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(tdf['time'])
```

This works but is not doing the correct thing.
Indeed, the measurements are not evenly time-spaced and if I just declare the time_points pandas DataFrame as the index of my frame, I get an error :

```
rdf.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(tdf['time'])

decomp = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(rdf)

elif freq is None:
raise ValueError("You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index")

ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index
```

I don't know how to correct this.
Also, it seems that pandas' `TimeSeries` are deprecated.

I tried this :

```
rdf = pd.Series({'light':light_points[:]})
rdf.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(tdf['time'])
```

But it gives me a length mismatch :

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 122 elements
```

Nevertheless, I don't understand where it comes from, as rdf['light'] and 
tdf['time'] are of same length...

Eventually, I tried by defining my rdf as a pandas Series :

```
rdf = pd.Series(light_points[:],index=pd.DatetimeIndex(time_points[:]))
```

And I get this :

```
ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index
```

Then, I tried instead replacing the index by

```
 pd.TimeSeries(time_points[:])
```

And it gives me an error on the seasonal_decompose method line :

```
AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'
```

How can I work with unevenly spaced data ?
I was thinking about creating an approximately evenly spaced time array by adding many unknown values between the existing values and using interpolation to "evaluate" those points, but I think there could be a cleaner and easier solution.

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`seasonal_decompose()` requires a `freq` that is either provided as part of the `DateTimeIndex` meta information, can be inferred by `pandas.Index.inferred_freq` or else by the user as an `integer` that gives the number of periods per cycle. e.g., 12 for monthly (from `docstring` for `seasonal_mean`):

> ```
> def seasonal_decompose(x, model="additive", filt=None, freq=None):
>     """
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     x : array-like
>         Time series
>     model : str {"additive", "multiplicative"}
>         Type of seasonal component. Abbreviations are accepted.
>     filt : array-like
>         The filter coefficients for filtering out the seasonal component.
>         The default is a symmetric moving average.
>     freq : int, optional
>         Frequency of the series. Must be used if x is not a pandas
>         object with a timeseries index.
> ```

To illustrate - using random sample data:

```
length = 400
x = np.sin(np.arange(length)) * 10 + np.random.randn(length)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2015, 1, 1), periods=length, freq='w'), columns=['value'])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 400 entries, 2015-01-04 to 2022-08-28
Freq: W-SUN

decomp = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df)
data = pd.concat([df, decomp.trend, decomp.seasonal, decomp.resid], axis=1)
data.columns = ['series', 'trend', 'seasonal', 'resid']

Data columns (total 4 columns):
series      400 non-null float64
trend       348 non-null float64
seasonal    400 non-null float64
resid       348 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 15.6 KB
```

So far, so good - now randomly dropping elements from the `DateTimeIndex` to create unevenly space data:

```
df = df.iloc[np.unique(np.random.randint(low=0, high=length, size=length * .8))]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 222 entries, 2015-01-11 to 2022-08-21
Data columns (total 1 columns):
value    222 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 3.5 KB

df.index.freq

None

df.index.inferred_freq

None
```

Running the `seasonal_decomp` on this data 'works':

```
decomp = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df, freq=52)

data = pd.concat([df, decomp.trend, decomp.seasonal, decomp.resid], axis=1)
data.columns = ['series', 'trend', 'seasonal', 'resid']

DatetimeIndex: 224 entries, 2015-01-04 to 2022-08-07
Data columns (total 4 columns):
series      224 non-null float64
trend       172 non-null float64
seasonal    224 non-null float64
resid       172 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 8.8 KB
```

The question is - how useful is the result. Even without gaps in the data that complicate inference of seasonal patterns (see example use of `.interpolate()` in the [release notes](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/release/version0.6.html?highlight=seasonal#seasonal-decomposition), `statsmodels` qualifies this procedure as follows:

> ```
> Notes
> -----
> This is a naive decomposition. More sophisticated methods should
> be preferred.
>
> The additive model is Y[t] = T[t] + S[t] + e[t]
>
> The multiplicative model is Y[t] = T[t] * S[t] * e[t]
>
> The seasonal component is first removed by applying a convolution
> filter to the data. The average of this smoothed series for each
> period is the returned seasonal component.
> ```

Comment: Why have you used `freq=52` -, why 52 not another number?

Comment: It's been a while but I believe because my example uses weekly random data - see above.