# ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, statsmodels

I have obtained time-series data this way:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
ts_log = DataReader('RUB=X',  'yahoo', datetime(2007,1,1), datetime(2016,8,30))["Adj Close"]
```

ts_log looks this way:

```
Date
2007-01-01    3.269759
2007-01-02    3.269759
2007-01-03    3.270519
  .....        ......
```

Then I want to get decomposition by using statsmodels:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
```

> ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index

To fix this I tried 2 approaches:

1) That won't work, because not every day has a value:

```
ts_log = pd.DataFrame(data=ts_log.values, index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2007, 1, 1), 
                                                              end = datetime(2016,8,30), freq='D'), columns=['usd/rub'])
```

2) I thought that casting index to datetime should work , but no:

`ts_log = pd.DataFrame(data=ts_log.values, index=pd.to_datetime(ts_log.index), columns=['usd/rub'])`

Exactly the same error.

How can I make things to work?

P.S. This code is pretty fine, but I have a bit different data, anyway it should help you catch up the idea:

```
length = 400
x = np.sin(np.arange(length)) * 10 + np.random.randn(length)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2015, 1, 1), periods=length, freq='w'), columns=['value'])
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df)
```

Comment: What error does your second attempt give? The one with `pd.to_datetime(ts_log.index)`.

Comment: @IanS Calling seasonal_decompose(df) just after that return same error `You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index` . I cant  set freq here(

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34494780/5276797

Comment: @IanS Thank you for the link - `decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log, freq = 52)` - now it works

Comment: But what does `freq = 52` - mean?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know this function... But a quick Google search (for 'seasonal_decompose freq') shows that you're not the only one having difficulty understanding this parameter.

Comment: From my understanding, the `freq` depends on the type of your Time Series. As in, if it is daily (e.g.: `2018-09-05`), means 52 days. If is set to monthly (`2018-09 | or 2018-Sep` means 52 months, and so on...

Comment: `freq` is deprecated, use `period` instead.