# Python seasonal_decompose function from Statsmodels library giving ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to decompose seasonality and trend of my time series data using seasonal_decompose function from Statsmodels library but I am getting ValueError

Data :

```
                    A (Current average)
     TS 
2017-12-01 00:01:00 3.274965
2017-12-01 00:02:00 3.274083
2017-12-01 00:03:00 3.262563
2017-12-01 00:04:00 3.278352
2017-12-01 00:05:00 3.251769
```

Index of data :

```
ts_log.index
```

output :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-01 00:01:00', '2017-12-01 00:02:00',
               '2017-12-01 00:03:00', '2017-12-01 00:04:00',
               '2017-12-01 00:05:00', '2017-12-01 00:06:00',
               '2017-12-01 00:07:00', '2017-12-01 00:08:00',
               '2017-12-01 00:09:00', '2017-12-01 00:10:00',
               ...
               '2018-01-04 23:26:00', '2018-01-04 23:27:00',
               '2018-01-04 23:28:00', '2018-01-04 23:29:00',
               '2018-01-04 23:30:00', '2018-01-04 23:31:00',
               '2018-01-04 23:32:00', '2018-01-04 23:33:00',
               '2018-01-04 23:34:00', '2018-01-04 23:35:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TS', length=50000, freq=None)
```

Decomposing seasonality

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
```

Error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-7ca5a90bdbf8> in <module>()
      1 from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
----> 2 decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
      3 
      4 trend = decomposition.trend
      5 seasonal = decomposition.seasonal

C:\Users\Paras Mani\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq, two_sided)
     82             freq = pfreq
     83         else:
---> 84             raise ValueError("You must specify a freq or x must be a "
     85                              "pandas object with a timeseries index with"
     86                              "a freq not set to None")

ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index witha freq not set to None
```

Here I am using timeseries index but frequency is set to None. How can I change the frequency.

Comment: You can set the freq by `ts_log.index.freq`. This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494780/time-series-analysis-unevenly-spaced-measures-pandas-statsmodels

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pandas dataframe with a `DateTimeIndex`, you can inspect its frequency attribute.

```
print(df.index.freq)
```

If this returns `None`, you can set the frequency by assigning directly to the `df.index.freq` attribute or by using the `df.asfreq()` method. Eg.

```
# Set df freq to 120 min
df.index.freq = '120t'
df.asfreq('120t')
```

Using [`df.asfreq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) will allow you to easily resample/convert between frequencies and handle resampling. You can find a list of valid offset aliases (the 't' part of the code) [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). Or you can run `pd.tseries.offsets.__all__` to get a list of valid offsets only (NB, this won't print aliases, so you'll see `Minute` instead of `min` or `t`).

Once your dataframe has a valid time you can run seasonal_decompose(). From experimenting in `statsmodels` 0.12.2, frequencies above 1 hour i.e. `freq` < `'60T'`, results in `ValueError: freq T not understood. Please report if you think this is in error.` being thrown. If this means you'll need to downsample your `df`, I'd recommend using as approach along the lines of the following `df.resample('1H').median()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(x, model='additive', filt=None, freq=52)
fig = decomposition.plot()
plt.show()
```