# Python: error when I use seasonal_decompose¶

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df:
                         M3.1.3
ts_dt   
2019-11-07 09:38:28.850 0.00441
2019-11-07 09:38:31.513 0.00440
2019-11-07 09:38:34.167 0.00434
2019-11-07 09:38:36.821 0.00439
2019-11-07 09:38:40.387 0.00442
```

where the index is a datatime. I would like to do some time series analysis like [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-end-to-end-project-on-time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-with-python-4835e6bf050b).

This is what I am doing

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
result = seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive')
```

and I got this error

```
ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index with a freq not set to None
```

Comment: I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494780/time-series-analysis-unevenly-spaced-measures-pandas-statsmodels)

Comment: It looks like you need to specify which column in your df contains the data, and what the frequency is. Try  seasonal_decompose(df.yourcolumn, freq=1, model='additive')

Comment: it should work for seasonal_decompose(df.yourcolumn, period=1, model='additive')