# Python trend analyse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried following a tutorial on how to get trends via pandas but I go the error message after I try to show the trends:
`ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index with a freq not set to None`

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('Sealevel.csv')

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']
df = df.set_index('Time')

%matplotlib inline

import statsmodels.api as sm 

test = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive')
fig = test.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Series Analysis - unevenly spaced measures - pandas + statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494780/time-series-analysis-unevenly-spaced-measures-pandas-statsmodels)

Comment: @E.Zeytinci YES, Thank you very much :)