# How to determine frequency for seasonal decomposition and other questions

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm still a beginner in time series forecasting and I'm trying to decompose my data, but it returns `ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index with a freq not set to None` , i already have a timeseries index and it's freq is None, my questions are

1. If i need to pass the freq parameter, how to know what numbers should i pass? I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494780/time-series-analysis-unevenly-spaced-measures-pandas-statsmodels) but i still don't understand, if this is my date values, what `freq` should i pass? and why?

```
timeseriesDF.index
Out[107]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01',
               '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01',
               '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01',
               ...
               '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30',
               '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30',
               '2019-03-30', '2019-03-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=1000, freq=None)
```

2. Is there anyway to solve the error besides passing the `freq` parameter?
3. Why does the `freq` seems like a must in seasonal decomposing?